# What restricition imposed on cursor variable name in plsql?

Tags: variables, plsql, cursor, naming-conventions, shadowing

I have executed following simple anonymous block in sql developer by expecting x number of rows to be deleted from "FOO" table however I ended up with unexpected outcome which in turn deleting entire rows.

```
DECLARE
  type pkarray IS VARRAY(3) OF RAW(16);
  ids pkarray;      
BEGIN  
  ids := pkarray('guid_value1','guid_value2','guid_value3');          
  FOR i in 1 .. 3 LOOP  
    FOR foo IN (SELECT FOO_ID FROM FOO WHERE BAR_ID = UPPER(ids(i))) LOOP                  
           DELETE FROM FOO WHERE FOO_ID = foo.FOO_ID;                  
    END LOOP;        
  END LOOP;      
END;
```

However when I changed the cursor variable 'foo" to something else like "abc", the program worked correctly by deleting x number of rows. The number x I knew in ahead of time.

Comment: It depends on how Oracle evaluates variables, table names, .... In your query, `foo.id` is treated like "the column `id` of the table `foo`" and not "the field `id` of the variable `foo`", thus the unexpected behaviour. You should be able to change this behaviour by changing the variable name or even by using an alias (different from `foo`) for the table `foo` in the query. There is a great answer about this somewhere here, just trying to find it

Comment: Scope and precedence rules apply to all variables, not just cursor records as in your example. Think about what should happen when you `select * from foo where fid = 23` and `fid` is both a column name in `foo` and a local variable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I still don't fully understand why it behaved that way due to my lack of understanding and experience in this subject matter. However based on the observation from executing the code I reconfirm to myself using the cursor var as a lower case table name produces negative consequences. I will keep reading upon related articles. I appreciate your time for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PL/SQL is case insensitive for identifiers, `foo` and `FOO` are equvalent. Let's reproduce part of your code, setting off variable names in lower case for clarity:

```
 FOR foo /*1*/ IN (SELECT foo_id FROM foo WHERE bar_id = UPPER(ids(i))) LOOP                  
     DELETE FROM foo /*2*/ WHERE foo_id = foo.foo_id;                  
 END LOOP;
```

We are dealing here with name shadowing. When compiler evaluates this expression

```
DELETE FROM foo WHERE foo_id = foo.foo_id;
```

it sees that needed identifiers `foo` and `foo_id` are known (in context of table definition). So there's no need to seek higher in syntax tree for definition of the utilized names. In other words the first `foo` (loop variable) is shadowed by table name and not used in compilation of the delete query, which is the same as

```
DELETE FROM foo WHERE foo_id = foo_id;
```

and its filter condition is true for all `foo_id` except `NULL`, what leads to deleting entire rows.

---

Luckily this problem can be solved once and for all with [naming conventions](https://www.google.com/search?q=plsql%20naming%20conventions):  in PL/SQL blocks use names with special prefixes etc., protecting your code from accidental intersection with schema objects names.